# Is there a way to set the value of variable thru the [this] variable?

Tags: typescript, this

I got a variable at the class level, say it is called "x".

It's no issue to run something like `this.x='some value';` within that component file, cause it works.

But what if you want to do this thru a function like the following:

```
setThisValue('x','some value');
```

Well, I made a poor attempt, knowing it would not work, I posted below.   Following clearly would not work. But what's the remedy?

```
setThisValue(key,val){
   this.key = val; // this clearly would not work.
   // short of doing eval, is there a way to make it happen? 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
this[key] = val;
```